# How to validate a form before submitting the information in vue3

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

Im new in Vue3 and im doing this program so that you can choose options, fill the information and then send it with fetch(). The problem i have, is that even if the field have error messages, the information is send anyway. My question is, how do i do so that the information is send only when all fields are correctly filled, without error messages. As you can see, i have already validated my fields. Can someone help me please.

This is my code

```js
//    <script setup>
import { ref, reactive } from 'vue';

const formData = reactive({
  name: '',
  phone: '',
  message: '',
  subject: 'general',
})

const subjects = [
  { value: 'general', label: 'Personal information' },
  { value: 'question', label: 'Ask your question' },
  { value: 'support', label: 'Support help' }
]

const validate = () => {
  errors.value = []
  if (formData.phone == '') {
    errors.value.push({ message: 'Phone number is missing' })
  }else if(!/^\d+$/.test(formData.phone)){
    errors.value.push({message: 'Please enter a valid phone number'})
  }

  if (formData.name == '') {
    errors.value.push({ message: 'Name is missing' })
  } else if (formData.name.length < 3) {
    errors.value.push({ message: 'The name must not be less than three letters' })
  }
}

const send = (e) => {
    validate()
  console.log(formData)
  fetch('URL', {
    method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: formData
  })
}

const errors = ref([])
```

```HTML
<template>
  <form @submit.prevent="send">
    <h1>Information</h1>

    <label for="alternativ">Your choice</label>
    <select id="alternativ" v-model="formData.subject">
      <option v-for="subject in subjects" :value="subject.value">{{ subject.label }}</option>
    </select>

    <div v-if="formData.subject !== 'support'">
      <label for="name">Name</label>
      <input id="name" v-model="formData.name">

      <label for="phone">Phone</label>
      <input id="phone" v-model="formData.phone" type="tel" maxlength="10">
      <p v-for="error in errors" class="error">{{ error.message }}</p>
      <textarea v-if="formData.subject === 'question'" id="message" v-model="formData.message"
        placeholder="Write your message..."></textarea>
      <button type="submit">Send</button>
    </div>

    <p v-if="formData.subject === 'support'">Technical support is performed by our expert in the chat. Click the support button and describe your case</p>
    <button v-if="formData.subject === 'support'" type="submit">Open support</button>
  </form>
</template>
```

```CSS
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1 {
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 32px;
}

form {
  width: 300px;
  padding: 16px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

label {
  width: 72px;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 12px;
}

#name,
#phone {
  width: 180px;
  padding: 3px 10px;
  border: 1px solid #f6f6f6;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  margin: 8px 0;
  display: inline-block;
}

textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #f6f6f6;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  margin: 8px 0;
  resize: none;
  display: block;
}

button {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  margin-top: 32px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: blue;
}
.error {
  color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a condition that does not send the request if there are any errors. One of the ways to do this can be by returning `true` or `false` from your `validate` method.

```
const validate = () => {
  errors.value = []
  if (formData.phone == '') {
    errors.value.push({ message: 'Phone number is missing' })
  }else if(!/^\d+$/.test(formData.phone)){
    errors.value.push({message: 'Please enter a valid phone number'})
  }

  if (formData.name == '') {
    errors.value.push({ message: 'Name is missing' })
  } else if (formData.name.length < 3) {
    errors.value.push({ message: 'The name must not be less than three letters' })
  }

  return errors.value.length === 0
}
```

And now in your `send` method you can check if `validate` returns true or false.

```
const send = (e) => {
  const isFormValid = validate()
  console.log(formData)

  if(isFormValid) { // Send the request only if there are no errors
    fetch('URL', {
      method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: formData
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Happy to help! I would appreciate it if you could accept the answer